# Absolutely positioned element is relative to scrollbar on parent element (with overflow auto) even though no scrollbar is visible

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

The situation is kind of difficult to explain because it requires a very specific setup.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The container element has `overflow-y: auto` which should show a scrollbar if required, however in this scenario no scrollbar is shown, but the red bar is positioned as if there was a scrollbar visible:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Every style that I've used in the example is required for the bug to occur. There must be a positioned flexbox item with a positioned element inside it that has overflow auto and within that there must be another absolutely positioned element.

If you run the snippet and open it in a full page then resize the window vertically, it magically fixes itself which is weird.

In other browsers (Firefox and Safari) it renders correctly:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Is there any way I can change the CSS slightly so that it renders without the gap? Is this actually a Chrome bug, and if so should I report it?

I've tested it in Chrome 61.0.3163.91 and 63.0.3218.0.

Comment: Does this solve your purpose? .container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow-y: initial;
}

Comment: Try using: `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Comment: @Sameer I do require that element to have `overflow: auto`. The example I gave is greatly simplified from what I am currently using, so I do need these styles to be present.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Yes that will work but I don't want a scrollbar to be shown if it isn't needed (the container element may have different scrollable elements inside it and I don't want to double up on the visible scrollbars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Chrome bug (and haven't found yet if it been filed already).

---

Workaround 1: Since flex row item defaults to vertically stretch, give the `flex-item` `height: 100%`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/231jLhq4/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Workaround 2: Add a wrapper (`inner`), set it to full width/height and give it the `overflow-y: auto`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/231jLhq4/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="top"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```